# how to draw line with mouse clicks in elm?

Tags: elm

I am new to Elm and I really confused about the whole style and how it works

I want to draw lines with mouse clicks. Those line should be end to end. it means that after the first 2 clicks, I can add line to the graph with every click.

This should use sampleOn and foldp.

I really have no idea how to do it, Could some one help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Ok, this sounds like a homework question but I'll bite because I wanted to try*

You'll first need a signal that tells you the position of the mouse every time click occurs. That's where `sampleOn` comes into play.

```elm
clickedPosition : Signal (Int, Int)
clickedPosition =
  Signal.sampleOn Mouse.clicks Mouse.position
```

Next you'll need a signal that keeps track of all previous click points. That's what `foldp` is used for. It folds to the past, letting you build up an array of x,y coordinates:

```elm
clickedPoints : Signal (List (Float, Float))
clickedPoints =
  foldp (\(x, y) points -> (toFloat x, toFloat y) :: points) [] clickedPosition
```

You can describe your scene as a function that takes a list of clicked points as well as the window size, and draw a path that connects all the points. The `adjustPoint` function converts the click position to a position on the collage:

```elm
scene : List (Float, Float) -> (Int, Int) -> Element
scene points (width, height) =
  let
    adjustPoint (x, y) =
      (x - toFloat width / 2, toFloat height / 2 - y)
  in
    collage width height
      [ traced (solid red)
        <| path
        <| List.map adjustPoint points
      ]
```

Lastly, we tie together the `clickedPoints` signal along with the `Window.dimensions` signal and map them in the `scene` function.

```elm
main : Signal Element
main =
  Signal.map2 scene clickedPoints Window.dimensions
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right. this is a homework problem, but it is not the exactly problem I need to do. I just rewrite my problem to this problem to get an example code, because I really have no idea how to start since this language is so weird. Thanks again!

Comment: hi,I thought I can finish my homework on my own by referencing ur code, but I fail to do it. Is that ok if I send my code to u in private and ask for ur help?

Comment: I'm unable to at the moment and you're probably under time constraints. Try asking around on the IRC channel: http://elm-lang.org/community